# No layout exists in original language

Tags: abap, adobe-form

In transaction `SFP` I want to upload a form.
[image]

After I do that, I want to activate and I get the following error:
[image]

I do not know if this info is relevant, but if I open the XML I see the following:
[image]

I can not change the language from the Form Builder, and if I change the language from the XML, it will not do me any good.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to log on in RO and then upload the form?

Comment: Yes, and I get the exact same error.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to upload an English version into a Romanian one?

Comment: I just try to upload the version I've been given, maybe I received a wrong version, good point.

Answer (score 1):

The message means that you try to activate form without any layout designed. It seems you created new form and just upload XML without any further actions.
Try to:

1. Either switch to *Layout* tab in `SFP` designer for at least 1 time after upload. This will create minimum default layout for the form.
2. Or select "Unknown layout type" in *Properties* tab
   And try to activate again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but here's what happens: 1. I do not have the tools to go to the 'Layout' tab, I tried it at a coworker who can open the 'Layout' tab, but he gets the same error. 2. I can not select the 'Unknown Layout Type' , I get the following error: 'Layout type "Unknown" is no longer valid'

Comment: What do you put in "I do not have the tools to go to the Layout tab"? I see this tab on your screenshot.

Comment: Well, I needed a Adobe LiveCycle Designer to access the Layout tab. I have installed it meanwhile.

Comment: Haha) How the hell do you tried to design forms without Adobe LC? It's unbelieveble.

Comment: Not design, just upload, and the fact that I have installed it, did not change absolutely anything in the problem.

Comment: Uploading doesn't mean activating by default. Have you tried option 1? Have it created any layout for the form (showing message *saved XXX bytes*)? Can you switch to created layout and change any element?